# What is clustering used for?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I know that clustering can be used for unsupervised learning and some people told me *for many more techniques*, but I was left with no answer, when I asked for what else clustering is used.

Comment: For grouping like with like. "Find me every picture that looks like this one."

Comment: Did you bother to read the Wikipedia article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labeling data is not always an easy task. There are occasion that the data in hand does not have label and you need to make a model using them. You have to find the similarities and differences in your input data. Clustering approaches try to find these similarities and differences to find similar data. Also they are used as a pre-processing before doing supervised classification. In cases that the input data does not have any label, employing clustering approaches can be a way to label the data and use them for training supervised models.